# Android 12 Upgrade - TextToSpeech setPitch() and setSpeechRate() not working

Tags: android

My Java app uses TextToSpeech, with setPitch() and setSpeechRate(). Since the recent upgrade to Android 12 API 32, these set methods no longer work. This is on some Samsung devices, and Google Pixel 5a. They worked before the upgrade, and have no effect now (although still return a "0" result).

I'm using the deprecated speak API:

`int speak (String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params)`

It looks like setPitch and setSpeechRate have been broken by the upgrade. On one device I tried it immediately before and immediately after upgrading, with no change to the app.

Perhaps the new API still works:

`public int speak (CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`

I haven't tried it yet, but thought I'd flag this and check for others' experiences straight away. Does anyone else have this problem, or any suggestions?

---

EDITS: Using the newer API does the same.

Using an emulator on API 32 it all works OK. Using a Galaxy S21 or Galaxy S22 on API 32 we get the problem. Both are using the com.google.android.tts TTS engine.

Curiously, it ignores setSpeechRate() *unless* it's over 2.0.

I've created an empty app with just TTS. SpeechRates from 0.2 to 2.0 speak as if they're 1.0. A speechRate of 2.1 speaks about double speed, as it should.

My code is below for reference:

```
void initTTS() {
   tts = new TextToSpeech (this, status -> {
        Log.d("MyApp", "TTS Init complete. status:" + status);

        // All of these speak at the same rate, as if they are 1.0
        speak(0.2f);
        speak(1.0f);
        speak(2.0f);

        // This speaks much faster, sounds like 2.1
        speak(2.1f);
    });
}

void speak(Float speechRate) {
    tts.setSpeechRate(speechRate);
    final Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putFloat(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME,1);
    tts.speak("This is my voice", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params, "1");
}
```

If you'd like to try this and report the result, please do. Don't forget to mention which API level you are on, and which device please.

Answer (score 0):

Our applications had the same problem. Speech rate is now always 1 or more than 2. And on different phones Samsung, Xiaomi. And on different versions of OS 10.12. It looks like a problem with updating the voice package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've just tried this again, without changing the app. The speech rate now works as expected, although pitch still doesn't. I guess there has been some sort of Android update that's partially fixed it. How is it for you?